# Error en mi código de bloques de blockchain

Tags: c++

Tengo una tarea de crear un blockchain, en este momento solo estoy creando la clase del bloque, todavía estoy probando cosas pero no entiendo porque no se imprimen las variables de mi bloque, no es algo que valla a usar en mi código de blockchain pero es para probar si las cosas están bien.

`cout<<newblock.Hash;` es el codigo que no está funcionando.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctime>

#include "Sha256.h"

using namespace std;

class Block{
    public:
        string Data = "";
        string PrevBlockHash = "";
        string Hash = "";

        string SetHash();
}

string Block::SetHash(){
    string headers = "";

    headers = Data + PrevBlockHash;

    Block::Hash = SHA256::cifrar(headers);

}

void NewBlock(string data, string prevBlockHash){
    Block newblock;
    newblock.Data = data;
    newblock.PrevBlockHash = prevBlockHash;
    newblock.Hash = "";


    newblock.SetHash();
    cout<<newblock.Hash;
}

int main(){
    NewBlock("hhh", "XB35G7F2K");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Mi único error era que mi función `string Block::SetHash` no tenía un `return()`.

se puede solucionar cambiando la función `string Block::SetHash` a `void Block::SetHash` o simplemente poniendo `return string()`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctime>

#include "Sha256.h"

using namespace std;

class Block{
    public:
        string Date = "";
        string Data = "";
        string PrevBlockHash = "";
        string Hash = "";

        void SetHash();
};

void Block::SetHash(){
    string headers = "";


    headers =Data + PrevBlockHash;

    Hash = SHA256::cifrar(headers);
}

void NewBlock(string data, string prevBlockHash){
    Block newblock;
    newblock.Date = "11/10/2020";
    newblock.Data = data;
    newblock.PrevBlockHash = prevBlockHash;
    newblock.Hash = "";


    newblock.SetHash();
    cout<<newblock.Hash<<"\n"<<newblock.Date;
}

int main(){
    NewBlock("hhh", "XB35G7F2K");

    return 0;
}
```